GNOME shell: How to prevent programs starting "Always on Visible Workspace"
When I run graphical programs in GNOME shell, they sometimes (but not always) start with "Always on Visible Workspace".  I don't know what is different between the times they do and don't start in that mode.
How can I prevent that?  I almost never want programs to start in this mode.
The programs affected include firefox (which I always start from gnome-terminal) and gnome-terminal (which I always start by clicking on an icon).  I think I've seen the problem with other apps too.
I'm using X.org.  As far as I can tell I'm not running anything like devilspie that might be likely candidates to interfere with this kind of thing after X programs have started.

You can use this wrapper, by example ~/bin/firefox:
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/firefox "$@" &
sleep 3
wmctrl -r firefox -b remove,sticky

For sure, you need to install wmctrl if needed.
Make sure you place the script earlier than other paths in PATH variables, Ex in ~/.bashrc:
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH


Thanks, I'll give this a try. Since opening the question I've noticed that I think even existing open windows somehow end up always visible. That leads me to question whether the problem was ever that they are always visible when they first open - perhaps they just turn always visible some time later.  Any idea why they might end up always visible in the first place?
